# Is $f \circ f^{-1}=id$ a sufficient criteria/check for diffeomorphism? Or what is?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Is $f \circ f^{-1}=id$ a sufficient criteria for diffeomorphism?

I recall having seen some version which had three functions in the composition.

But I also think of reading that $f \circ f^{-1}=id$ implies that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ must be smooth. But I don't know if this also proves bijectivity?

Particularly, http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/michael.murray/dg_hons/node7.html

> If $ f$ is a diffeomorphism  $ f \circ f^{-1} = 1_{ \mathbb{R}^n}$

But is this a $\iff$ or $\implies$?

---

Also confused as to whether $f \circ f^{-1}$ really produces $\mathbb{R}$, since $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If Lemma 1.2 requires that $\phi^{-1}$ would be onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $x\mapsto \begin{cases}x & x\neq 0,1\\ 1 & x=0 \\ 0&x=1\end{cases}$ a diffeo?

Comment: Of course not ! You should see the definition of a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Invertibility is one requirement. Just as important is the requirement that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are $C^\infty$, and the definition of a function between manifolds being $C^\infty$ usually uses a certain composition of three functions.